# Rust Book's Chapter 8 - Text Interface

Tags: beginner, rust

I recently finished chapter 8 of Rust's book, and below is my solution to the [third exercise](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#summary):

> Using a hash map and vectors, create a text interface to allow a user
> to add employee names to a department in a company. For example, “Add
> Sally to Engineering” or “Add Amir to Sales.” Then let the user
> retrieve a list of all people in a department or all people in the
> company by department, sorted alphabetically.

I'd appreciate pointers on how the code can be improved. Thanks in advance.

```
use std::io;
use std::collections::HashMap;

//An attempt at Rust book's chapter 8's third exercise:
//https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html

fn main() {
    println!("The Office - Text Interface.");
    println!();
    println!("Enter a query, type HELP for a list of keyword and their functions, or type EXIT to exit.");
    println!();

    //build hashmap{department: vec[names]} database, insert default values
    let mut company = HashMap::new();
    
    let depts = vec!["SALES", "ENGINEERING", "HR", "SANITATION"];

    let sales = vec!["Sally", "Jordan", "Charlie", "Abigail"];
    let engineering = vec!["Suzy", "Jay", "Chi", "Amy"];
    let hr = vec!["Son", "Jack", "Chia", "Anna"];
    let sanitation = vec!["August", "Entangle", "Will", "Jada"];
    let tup = [sales, engineering, hr, sanitation];

    let mut g: Vec<_> = Vec::new();
    company = depts.into_iter()
    .map(|x| x.to_string())
    .zip(tup.iter().map(|y| {g = y.iter().map(|q| q.to_string()).collect(); g.clone()}))
    .collect();

    let keywords = ["ADD", "LIST", "UPDATE", "REMOVE", "HELP", "EXIT"];

    // loop the input part of the text interface.
    //validate first keyword, send queries to functions.
    loop {
        let mut query = String::new();
        println!("::");

        //check for empty input
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut query).expect("Enter a valid input");
        query = query.trim().to_string();
        // println!("{}", query);
        if query.is_empty() {
            println!("Invalid input. Type HELP for a keyword reference.");
            continue;
        }

        //check for valid first keyword
        let keyword = query.split_whitespace().next().unwrap().to_uppercase();
        if !keywords.contains(&&keyword[..]) {
            println!("Invalid Keyword. Type HELP for a keyword reference.");
            continue;
        }

        //keyword validated. Call the function.
        let mut query = query.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<_>>();
        match &&keyword[..] {
            &"EXIT" => return,
            &"HELP" => help(),
            &"ADD" => add(&mut query, &mut company),
            &"LIST" => list(&mut query, &mut company),
            &"UPDATE" => update(&mut query, &mut company),
            &"REMOVE" => remove(&mut query, &mut company),
            _ => (),
        }
        // println!("{:?}", company); //debug purposes: print the entire hashmap on each loop to monitor changes.
        continue;
    }
}

fn add(q: &mut Vec<&str>, company: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {

    //validate add syntax
    let length = q.len();
    if length < 3 || length > 4 {
        println!("Invalid ADD syntax. Type HELP for a keyword reference.");
        return;
    }

    //add a new department
    if length == 3 {
        match (q[0], q[1], q[2]) {
            ("ADD", "-D", d) => {

                //check if dept exists
                let dept = d.to_uppercase();
                if company.contains_key(&dept) {
                    println!("Department {} already exists.", d);
                    return;
                }

                //add dept
                company.entry(dept).or_insert(Vec::new());
                println!("Created department {}.", d);
                return;

            }

            _ => {
                println!("Invalid syntax.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //add a person to a department
    if length == 4 {
        match (q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3]) {
            ("ADD", name, "TO", d) => {

                //check if dept exists
                let dept = d.to_uppercase();
                if !company.contains_key(&dept) {
                    println!("Department {} does not exist.", d);
                    return;
                }

                //check if name already exists in dept
                if company[&dept].contains(&name.to_owned()) {
                    println!("The name {} already exists in {}.", name, dept);
                    return;
                }
                //add name to vector
                (*company.get_mut(&dept).unwrap()).push(name.to_owned());
                println!("Added {} to {}.", name, d);
            }
            _ => {
                println!("Invalid Syntax");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn list(q: &mut Vec<&str>, company: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {

    //sanitize input
    let length = q.len();
    if length != 2 && length !=4 {
        println!("Invalid number of arguments.");
        return;
    }

    if length == 2 {
        match (q[0], q[1]) {

            //list all depts
            ("LIST", "-D") => {
                let mut depts: Vec<_> = company.keys().collect();
                depts.sort();
                for d in depts {
                    println!("{}", d);
                }
                return;
            }

            //list everyone in all depts, sorted alphabetically
            ("LIST", "-E") => {
                for (dept, mut names) in company.clone() {
                    println!("---{}---", dept);
                    names.sort();
                    for name in names {
                        println!("{}", name);
                    }
                }
            }
            _ => {
                println!("Invalid Syntax.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    if length == 4 {
        match (q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3]) {
            ("LIST", "-E", "IN", d) => {

                //check if dept exists
                let dept = d.to_uppercase();
                if !company.contains_key(&dept) {
                    println!("Department {} does not exist.", d);
                    return;
                }

                //list all in department
                println!("---{}---", dept);
                (*company.get_mut(&dept).unwrap()).sort();
                for name in &company[&dept] {
                    println!("{}", name);
                }
            }
            _ => {
                println!("Invalid Syntax.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn update(q: &mut Vec<&str>, company: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {
    let length = q.len();

    if length != 5 && length != 6 {
        println!("Invalid UPDATE syntax.");
        return;
    }

    if length == 5 {
        match (q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3], q[4]) {

            //update a department
            ("UPDATE", "-D", old_d, "TO", new_d) => {

                //check if dept exists
                let old_dept = old_d.to_uppercase();
                let new_dept = new_d.to_uppercase();
                if !company.contains_key(&old_dept) {
                    println!("Department {} does not exist.", old_d);
                    return;
                }
                if company.contains_key(&new_dept) {
                    println!("Department {} already exists.", new_d);
                    return;
                }

                //rename dept. Technique is to build a new vector with that same name since you
                //cannot change the key of a hash map.
                let temp_dept = company.get(&old_dept).unwrap().clone();
                company.insert(new_dept.to_uppercase(), temp_dept);
                company.remove(&old_dept);
                println!("Changed Department {} to {}.", old_d, new_d);
                return;

            }
            _ => {
                println!("Invalid syntax.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //change a name in a department
    match (q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3], q[4], q[5]) {
        ("UPDATE", old_name, "FROM", d, "TO", new_name) => {

            //check if dept exists
            let dept = d.to_uppercase();
            if !company.contains_key(&dept) {
                println!("Department {} does not exist.", d);
                return;
            }

            //check if old name and new name exist
            if !company[&dept].contains(&old_name.to_owned()) {
                println!("The name {} does not exist in {}.", old_name, dept);
                return;
            }
            if company[&dept].contains(&new_name.to_owned()) {
                println!("The name {} already exists in {}.", new_name, dept);
                return;
            }

            //update the name.
            for (i, name) in company[&dept].clone().iter().enumerate() {
                if name == old_name {
                    (*company.get_mut(&dept).unwrap())[i] = new_name.to_owned();
                    println!("Changed {} in {} to {}.", old_name, dept, new_name);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        _ => {
            println!("Invalid Syntax.");
            return;
        }
    }
}

fn remove(q: &mut Vec<&str>, company: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {
    let length = q.len();

    if length !=3 && length !=4 {
        println!("Invalid REMOVE syntax.");
        return;
    }

    if length == 3 {
        match (q[0], q[1], q[2]) {
            ("REMOVE", "-D", d) => {

                //check if dept exists
                let dept = d.to_uppercase();
                if !company.contains_key(&dept) {
                    println!("Department {} does not exist.", d);
                    return;
                }

                //remove the department.
                company.remove(&dept);
                println!("Removed department {}.", d);
                return;

            }
            _ => {
                println!("Invalid Syntax.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //remove a person
    match (q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3]) {
        ("REMOVE", name, "FROM", d) => {

            //check if dept exists
            let dept = d.to_uppercase();
            if !company.contains_key(&dept) {
                println!("Department {} does not exist.", d);
                return;
            }

            //check if name exists
            if !company[&dept].contains(&name.to_owned()) {
                println!("The name {} does not exist in {}.", name, dept);
                return;
            }

            //remove the name
            for (i, _name) in company[&dept].clone().iter().enumerate() {
                if _name == name {
                    (*company.get_mut(&dept).unwrap()).remove(i);
                    println!("Removed {} from {}.", name, dept);
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
        _ => {
            println!("Invalid Syntax.");
            return;
        }
    }
}

fn help() {
    println!("The Office - KEYWORD HELP");
    println!();
    println!("Note: All keywords are case-sensitive.");
    println!("Keywords: \nLIST - Lists items in the database");
    println!("Usage:    LIST -E - Lists all employees");
    println!("          LIST -E IN [DEPARTMENT] - Lists all employees in specified department.");
    println!("          LIST -D - Lists all departmnets in the company");
    println!();
    println!("ADD -     Adds items to the database.");
    println!("Usage:    ADD [name] TO [department] - Adds the name to the specified department.");
    println!("          ADD -D [department] - Adds the department to the roster.");
    println!();
    println!("REMOVE -  Removes items from the database.");
    println!("          REMOVE -D [department] - Removes the particular department from the database.");
    println!("          REMOVE [name] FROM [department] - Removes the person from the specified department.");
    println!();
    println!("UPDATE -  Changes records in the database.");
    println!("Usage:    UPDATE -D [old name] TO [new name] - Changes a department's name.");
    println!("          UPDATE [old name] FROM [department] TO [new name] - Changes a person's name.");
    println!();
    println!("HELP -    Prints this help screen.");
    println!();
    println!("EXIT -    Exits the program.")
}
```

Comment: To improve readability, run `cargo fmt` in your project root. This will run [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt) which will automatically format your code according to the official code style. If you want, you can [configure rustfmt](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/?version=master&search=) to behave differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review.

## Formatting

The first thing I did to your code was to apply `rustfmt` by typing
`cargo fmt`.  `rustfmt` formats your code to fit with Rust's standard
formatting guidelines.  Here's some notable changes.

```
-    company = depts.into_iter()
-    .map(|x| x.to_string())
-    .zip(tup.iter().map(|y| {g = y.iter().map(|q| q.to_string()).collect(); g.clone()}))
-    .collect();
+    company = depts
+        .into_iter()
+        .map(|x| x.to_string())
+        .zip(tup.iter().map(|y| {
+            g = y.iter().map(|q| q.to_string()).collect();
+            g.clone()
+        }))
+        .collect();
```

Method invocation chains are indented.  Complex closures are formatted
over several lines.

```
-    if length !=3 && length !=4 {
+    if length != 3 && length != 4 {
```

Most binary operators are surrounded by spaces.

## Clippy

After that, `cargo clippy` pointed out some issues with your code.

```
warning: unneeded `return` statement
   --> src\main.rs:270:13
    |
270 |             return;
    |             ^^^^^^^ help: remove `return`
    |
    = note: `#[warn(clippy::needless_return)]` on by default
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#needless_return

warning: unneeded `return` statement
   --> src\main.rs:332:13
    |
332 |             return;
    |             ^^^^^^^ help: remove `return`
    |
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#needless_return
```

In Rust, functions automatically return when control flow reaches the
end of the function body, so the explicit `return`s are unnecessary.

```
warning: value assigned to `company` is never read
  --> src\main.rs:16:9
   |
16 |     let mut company = HashMap::new();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_assignments)]` on by default
   = help: maybe it is overwritten before being read?
```

You assigned an initial value to `company`, but overwrote it
afterwards.  It is recommended to postpone the declaration of
`company` to the place you calculate it.

```
warning: you don't need to add `&` to both the expression and the patterns
  --> src\main.rs:64:9
   |
64 | /         match &&keyword[..] {
65 | |             &"EXIT" => return,
66 | |             &"HELP" => help(),
67 | |             &"ADD" => add(&mut query, &mut company),
...  |
71 | |             _ => (),
72 | |         }
   | |_________^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::match_ref_pats)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#match_ref_pats
help: try
   |
64 |         match &keyword[..] {
65 |             "EXIT" => return,
66 |             "HELP" => help(),
67 |             "ADD" => add(&mut query, &mut company),
68 |             "LIST" => list(&mut query, &mut company),
69 |             "UPDATE" => update(&mut query, &mut company),
 ...
```

Self explanatory.

```
warning: use of `or_insert` followed by a function call
  --> src\main.rs:98:37
   |
98 |                 company.entry(dept).or_insert(Vec::new());
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: try this: `or_insert_with(Vec::new)`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::or_fun_call)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#or_fun_call
```

`.or_insert(Vec::new())` always constructs the vector; if the entry
already exists, the newly constructed empty vector is discarded.  A
better alternative is `.or_default(Vec::new)`.  (It probably doesn't
make a big difference in this case though.)

## Structuring data

In Chapter 5 [Using Structs to Structure Related Data](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-00-structs.html), we learned
to use structs and methods to organize our data.  We can define some
`struct`s to clarify the meaning of our data:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Department {
    employees: Vec<String>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Company {
    departments: HashMap<String, Department>,
}
```

And we can build the preset data in an associated function:

```
impl Company {
    fn preset() -> Self {
        let departments = &[
            ("SALES", &["Sally", "Jordan", "Charlie", "Abigail"]),
            ("ENGINEERING", &["Suzy", "Jay", "Chi", "Amy"]),
            ("HR", &["Son", "Jack", "Chia", "Anna"]),
            ("SANITATION", &["August", "Entangle", "Will", "Jada"]),
        ];

        Company {
            departments: departments
                .iter()
                .map(|&(name, department)| {
                    (
                        name.to_string(),
                        Department {
                            employees: department.iter().map(|&s| s.to_string()).collect(),
                        },
                    )
                })
                .collect(),
        }
    }
}
```

(Personally, I would prefer using serialization instead of hardcoding
the preset data.)

## Unnecessary allocation

In `main`, there is an unnecessary allocation:

```
query = query.trim().to_string();
```

You can simply make a reference into the original input:

```
let query = query.trim();
```

Note that [shadowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html#shadowing) is used here to maintain the variable that
owns the original string.

## Input parsing

You first check for empty input, and then use `.next().unwrap()`.
Just use a `match`:

```
let query = query.trim();
let mut args = query.split_whitespace();

match args.next() {
    None => println!("Empty input. Type HELP for a keyword reference."),
    Some("ADD") => execute::add(args.collect(), &mut company),
    Some("EXIT") => return,
    Some("HELP") => help(),
    Some("LIST") => execute::list(args.collect(), &mut company),
    Some("REMOVE") => execute::remove(args.collect(), &mut company),
    Some("UPDATE") => execute::update(args.collect(), &mut company),
    Some(_) => println!("Invalid Keyword. Type HELP for a keyword reference."),
}
```

I put all the helper functions in a `execute` module.  I also changed
the parsing functions to take `args` by value.  The keyword is
excluded from the list of arguments.

## `add`

Checking if a department exists can be done with the entry API:

```
let department = department.to_uppercase();
match departments.entry(&department) {
    Entry::Occupied(_) => println!("Department {} already exists.", d),
    Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
        entry.insert(Department::new());
        println!("Created department {}.", d);
    }
}
```

In fact, the whole function can be simplified with pattern matching:

```
pub fn add(args: &[&str], company: &mut Company) {
    let departments = &mut company.departments;

    match *args {
        ["-D", department] => {
            use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;

            let department = department.to_uppercase();

            match departments.entry(department) {
                Entry::Occupied(entry) => {
                    println!("Department {} already exists.", entry.key())
                }
                Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
                    println!("Created department {}.", entry.key());
                    entry.insert(Department::new());
                }
            }
        }
        [name, "TO", department] => {
            let department = department.to_uppercase();

            let employees = match departments.get_mut(&department) {
                None => {
                    println!("Department {} does not exist.", department);
                    return;
                }
                Some(department) => &mut department.employees,
            };

            if employees.iter().any(|employee| employee == name) {
                println!("The name {} already exists in {}.", name, department);
            } else {
                employees.push(name.to_string());
                println!("Added {} to {}.", name, department);
            }
        }
        _ => println!("Invalid syntax."),
    }
}
```

Other functions can be simplified in a similar fashion.

## `continue`

Similar to the implicit `return`, you do not need to explicitly
continue to the next iteration of the loop at the end of the loop
body.

## `help`

The [`indoc`](https://docs.rs/indoc/1.0/indoc/) crate provides a nice way to write multiline string
literals:

```
pub fn help() {
    println!(indoc! { r#"
        <fill in text here>
    "#})
}
```

The indentation common to every line will be stripped, and the rest of
the indentation will be preserved.

Comment: This is detailed and helpful, thanks a lot. Using the indoc crate especially is one tip I hadn't even considered.